# Copy File Having same name but add number of copies to it programatically

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io

I want to copy file in same place if exist already then name should be concatenated with number of copies like we do it manually in windows.

`FileName`:- `MyPresentation.pptx to Mypresentation - copy 1.pptx`

I only found this code

```
FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceFileName, desFileName)
IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, desFileName)
```

Which only allows to over write and throws exception for next copy.

Comment: You need to check the destination directory for files with that naming pattern then figure out the correct name to use.

Comment: I want to use automatic code like we do in windows

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution -an algorithm which iterate each file and user counter to name the file

```
    Dim sourceFileName As String = "C:\Users\itapi\Desktop\2a.png" 
    Dim NewFile As String = ""
    Dim count As Integer = 1

    While FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(sourceFileName)

        NewFile = sourceFileName + "(" + count.ToString + ")"


    End While

    IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, NewFile)
```

Comment: @KhanEngineer Then it would iterate through less files. Still should work. if i helped you it would be kind to accept my answer :)  any other questions?

Comment: not working for me I need automatic way and your answer also does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really aware about an automatic method, but I have implemented something like this earlier, If you delete a file, this will work just like windows does. may be it helps -

```
        string formatingString = " Copy ({0})";

        string originalDestinationName = "E:\\MyPresentation.txt";
        string sourceFileName = "C:\\Data\\MyPresentation.txt";


        int counter = 0;
        string actualDestinationPath =  originalDestinationName;
        string fileNameWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalDestinationName);
        string actualDestinationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(originalDestinationName);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(originalDestinationName);
        //Check if the file exisits
        while (File.Exists(actualDestinationPath))
        {
             counter ++;
             actualDestinationPath = actualDestinationDirectory + fileNameWithoutExt + string.Format(formatingString,counter) + ext;

        }
        File.Copy(sourceFileName,  actualDestinationPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir: some files are so big and full of past events that it would be difficult to re-create that file. My 50+ page personal diary file contained many past events of my Father's time, which is rather impossible to remember as I don't remember all the content I had collected. Moreover, it turned into editable text paragraphs and many of the paragraphs turned into non-editable image forms; I am still struggling to convert them back into Editable Text, which I find as an impossible task. Moreover, you have put code for but you did not mention which program can run it!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you create new file if file already exist and read the content from source and write it to new file.